# When low-level formatting a floppy, how does one ensure any existing sector markers are overwritten?

Tags: floppy-disk

If a formatted floppy diskette is reformatted with a low-level¹
format, how does the formatting routine make sure that any previous
sector markers are fully overwritten? In particular, how does it make
sure that the first sector marker from any previous format is
overwritten?

(If a previous sector marker was not properly overwritten that could
obviously confuse any routines later reading the floppy diskette.)

---

¹<sub>"Low-level" appears to be modern (late-80s/early-90s)
terminology used to distinguish rewriting the sector markers on
soft-sectored diskettes from merely rewriting the filesystem
information.</sub>

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Low-level formats of floppies do not do individual sector writes, as
normally done when writing new data to a sector of an
already-formatted floppy, but instead rewrite each entire track in one
operation. This is done in such a way that the entire track, including
unused areas, is overwritten, ensuring that there will be no data left
from previous formats.

The data sheet for the [Fujitsu MB8877A Floppy Disk
Formatter/Controller (FDC)](https://www.tim-mann.org/max80/Appendix_D_Updated.pdf) explains this fairly clearly.
Page 8 contains the details of track formatting, including the gaps
between sectors:

[image: Track format diagram]

Further down on the page are the exact details of byte values and
counts; for our purposes all that's really important is that all of
the gaps in an MFM ("double-density") format are a continuous stream
of $4E values.

Page 10 gives the details of what data to feed to the FDC during a "write
track" command in order to format a track:

[image: Double-density MFM format with write-track command]

What happens during this sequence is that you seek the head to the
track you want to format, send a "write track" command, and write $4E
to the data register (DR), indicating that you want the controller to
write a post-index gap byte when it starts writing. This will clear
the data request bit (DRQ) in the status register.

The controller will wait until it's detected the index mark (via the
small hole near the centre of the diskette passing an optical sensor)
and then start writing that byte. In the meantime you must be checking
the DRQ bit; when it becomes set you must write another $4E to the DR,
doing this 80 more times. This creates the post-index gap. You then
carry on writing the other bytes described in the table above until
you've written address markers, data fields and gaps for all of the
sectors.

At this point there's still a gap of variable size to be written. (The
size varies due to small variations in the speed of the motor.)
To fill this out completely you continue to
write $4E filler bytes as above until the controller sets its INTRQ
line, which indicates that it's again seen the index hole and you are
now writing again over the post-index gap you wrote at the start of
the track format operation. This ensures that all data previously on
the track have been overwritten. A little bit of "overflow" here does
no harm because it's merely writing into the unused space of the
post-index gap.

Comment: "(The size varies because tracks get longer as you move outward from the centre of the diskette.)" -- no, at least until the bitrate is not constant.

Comment: @lvd, The 3 1/2" floppies for the original Macintosh computer wrote more sectors in the outer tracks than in the inner tracks. They varied the rotation rate of the disk rather than varying the number of bits per second. https://siber-sonic.com/mac/newmillfloppy.html

Comment: @SolomonSlow True, but lvd is correct for this example, which uses the more common constant bit rate. This was just a brain fart on my part; I've fixed the post.

Comment: This answer is explaining perfectly that the whole length of the track gets rewritten. It does not talk about the width of the track. The canonical example where this goes wrong in practise is reformatting a 360K floppy (40 tracks) in a 1.2MB drive (80 tracks, double-stepped). The tracks written by the 80-track drive are narrower than tracks written by a 40-track drive, so the formatting of every other track in the 80-track drive might leave residues of the previous contents between the small new tracks. This residue can be picked up by a 40-track drive which reads wider tracks.

Comment: @Michael Right: I was trying to answer a specific question here (brought up elsewhere, actually) about how this works _within one particular format_; compatibility between different drive types is a completely different question. And note that it's not just 1.2 MB HD drives that have this issue; 720 KB double-density drives have the same interchangability problem with 360 KB DSDD drives.